# Create scrollable layout for chat

Tags: android, chat

I was looking for a way to implement a chat in my application. I have already implemented a way of getting incoming messages, and outgoing messages. So my only problem is how to create a layout for the chat. But i really can't figure it out.
After looking i found a layout that looks a like a chat (http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/source/browse/trunk/res/layout/messaging_screen.xml?r=6):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--    
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:text="Friend:"
    />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/friendUserName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:editable="false" />
    --> 
    <TextView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                        android:text="Messages:"/>

    <EditText   android:id="@+id/messageHistory"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:clickable="true"        
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:scrollbarSize="10px"
                    /> 

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText       android:id="@+id/message"
                                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                        android:gravity="top"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        />

                    <Button android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="4"
                                android:text="Send"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know if i am using it in a wrong way, but every incoming message always appears in the same text view, overwriting the message that was there before, with new incoming one. I suppose that probably i need to do something more for the JAVA side.

In other words what i want, is the place where the messages appear to be scrollable, and that every new message arriving should appear in the right-side, and one after another. The outgoing messages should appear left-side. I'm talking of course about the look of the SMS app in i-phone etc.

I don't understand how to do this. If someone knows a workaround, or any info on how to implement this, it would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a screen with a `ListView` to display all the individual chat message history and an `EditText` at the bottom for the user to enter new text. There may be various support UI elements such as a title at the top and a 'Send' button.

Each `ListView` item will display the message as well as date stamp and other information if you want. You can use different backgrounds for incoming and outgoing messages.

Find any example for `ListView` and start from there.

Comment: Will i need one adapter and one list view for showing incoming and outgoing messages?

Comment: You will use one ListView for showing all messages in a single stack ordered by time. You will want to do some decoration to indicate which list items are incoming and which items are outgoing. In your first implementation simply put the word "incoming" or "outgoing" into the list item via the SimpleAdapter you will start with. Later, you can do all sorts of decoration depending on incoming/outgoing such as left/right justified, different colors, thought bubbles. As a particularly advanced exercise, you can use 9-patch backgrounds and make your chat interface look just like iPhone.

Comment: thnx a lot, i'll try to do as you say

Comment: Could you maybe take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624324/error-receiving-broadcastreceiver-messages ??

Comment: The link you asked me to review is from a user who implemented a ListView and was having a NullPointerException because his ArrayAdapter used the wrong kind of Context pointer. He was headed in the right direction and probably fixed his problem easily. You, on the other hand, must implement a ListView or GridView in order to get the dynamic-number-of-items list you need. Search for an "example" or "tutorial" and find something outside of StackOverflow.com, which is better for fixing problems rather than finding cut-and-paste solutions. The ListView tutorial you choose needn't be for Chat view.

Comment: Thnx for your interest. The link i asked you to see is a question of mine. I tried to create the ListView but i got stuck on this problem, and i wanted an opinion if the way i am trying to implement it is right or if it's all wrong and i should start all over again. I implemented the adapter from a tutorial, but it had static data, and when i try to dynamically "feed" it with my data, i get the error. I edited again the question in the link i sent you, if you could take a look one more time i would me more than greatfull..

Comment: @Hoan's answer looks good and you are headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `ListView` which shows your messages. Any message will be an item in your `ListView`. For the content, you'll have to implement an `Adapter` which knows your message datastructure. Good example of ListView, Adapter and custom views inside your ListView is http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: So you mean that no TextView will be used to show the messages?? And you also mean that i will create one ListView for both incoming-outgoing messages and i will have to implement in the adapter the way the incoming and outgoing messages appear??