# Error receiving BroadcastReceiver messages

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have a BroadcastReceiver, implemented in an Activity Class, which accepts incoming  messages via Google Cloud Message. I want to use this class as a chat, so after i have incoming messages, I use a void:

```
public void Chatpat(String name, String message){

        chatinput.add(name);
        chatinput.add(message);


        Chat chat_data[] = new Chat[chatinput.size()];
        chatinput.toArray();


        ChatAdapter adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.listview_item_row, chat_data);

        chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        chatList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return;
    }
```

As i said i collect the incoming messages, and try to create a layout so that i can show them. My ChatAdapter handles this. The problem is that i get an error when i try to get the messages from the BroadcastReceiver. I use this line,

```
Chatpat(message_name, message_chat);
```

to collect the incoming messages:

```
String message_name = intent.getExtras().getString(NAME_MESSAGED);
String message_chat = intent.getExtras().getString(CHAT_MESSAGED);
```

Hopefully i wish that my adapter would be able, after that, to create a ListView which shows the message i got, and so on. The problem is that i get an error and the app crashes:

```
03-25 22:22:09.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.cabman.lol.ok.DISPLAY_MESSAGE (has extras) } in com.cabman.lol.ok.UserComActivity$1@44ee7778
```

Because of that i also get a NullPointerException inside Chatpat void. If i remove:

```
Chatpat(message_name, message_chat);
```

from inside the BroadcastReceiver, the messages are coming in the correct way without any problem..
I do not understand why this happens. I believe that the problem has to be with the fact that i use that incoming messages to initiate Chatpat, wich create a list view to show the messages.

The really weird thing is that i tried to feed the Chatpat, with other sources and though it works, if i try to print out a value, i get the same Error again, about the receiving Intent.

This is the whole Activity:

```
public class UserComActivity extends Activity{
List<String> messages;
List<String> names;
private ListView chatList;
SessionManager session;
EditText userText;
EditText chatText;
UserFunctions user = new UserFunctions();
String informchat = "yes";
String message_gcm;
Boolean i = false;
Chat chat_data[] ;
ArrayList<String> chatinput = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userchat);


    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    //chatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);
    userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);






    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> comu = session.matchUserDetails();


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String message = userText.getText().toString();


            if (i == false){
     session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
     HashMap<String, String> comu = session.matchUserDetails();
             String gcm = comu.get(SessionManager.KEY_GCM);
             HashMap<String, String> co = session.getUserDetails();
             String name = co.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

             System.out.println("UserComActivity:");
             System.out.println(name);
             System.out.println(gcm);

             chatText.setText(name +": "+ message);

          //   user.sendMessage(name, gcm, regId, message);
            }
            else if (i == true){


            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            HashMap<String, String> co = session.getUserDetails();
            String name = co.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME); 

         //   user.sendMessage(name, message_gcm, regId, message);

            }
        }
});

}



/**
public ArrayList<String> addChat(String name, String message){


    chatinput.add(name);
    chatinput.add(message);

    return chatinput;



}**/

    public void Chatpat(String name, String message){

        chatinput.add(name);
        chatinput.add(message);




        Chat chat_data[] = new Chat[chatinput.size()];
        chatinput.toArray(chat_data);




        ChatAdapter adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.listview_item_row, chat_data);

        chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        chatList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return;
    }



private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        i = true;
        String message_tag = intent.getExtras().getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        if(message_tag.equals("chat")){

        String message_name = intent.getExtras().getString(NAME_MESSAGED);
       String message_chat = intent.getExtras().getString(CHAT_MESSAGED);




         Chatpat(message_name, message_chat);

        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

These are the classes that i use to create the list view to show the text i want in the activity:

```
public class Chat {

public String name;
public String message;
public Chat(){
    super();
}

public Chat(String name, String message) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.message = message;
    //System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println("Chat!!!!!!");
}
```

}

and:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chat>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
Chat data[] = null;


    public ChatAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, 
Chat[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ChatHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ChatHolder();
        holder.txtUName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        holder.txtMessage = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtChat);
        System.out.println("ChatAdapter");
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ChatHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Chat chat = data[position];
    holder.txtMessage.setText(chat.message);
    holder.txtUName.setText(chat.name);
    System.out.println("ChatAdapter");
    return row;
}

static class ChatHolder
{

    TextView txtUName;
    TextView txtMessage;
}
```

}

The LogCat:

```
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving     broadcast Intent { act=com.cabman.lol.ok.DISPLAY_MESSAGE (has extras) } in   com.cabman.lol.ok.UserComActivity$1@44e877d0
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:905)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:523)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at com.cabman.lol.ok.UserComActivity.Chatpat(UserComActivity.java:149)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at com.cabman.lol.ok.UserComActivity$1.onReceive(UserComActivity.java:184)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
03-26 02:29:28.807: E/AndroidRuntime(5063):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: your problem solved or not?

Comment: no not solved, i dont even know what the problem is.

Comment: can i known what u are trying to do?

Comment: I would like to create a chat in this activity. I have a server, in which i upload the message sent from a user, and by using the gcm_id of the target device, i send the message. In this particular samples of code, i am trying to create a layout, to show the messages. I have create a adapter for this reason. The problem is, that by trying get the messages from the BroadcastReceiver, the app crashes.

Comment: Well as i checked, the messages do arrive correctly but i still get the Exception. So probably the adapter causes the whole problem?

Comment: yes Chatpat class causing problem. you can try to make BroadcastReceiver as inner class of Activity and then pass Activity Context to ChatAdapter as first parameter at time of object creation

Comment: Well not sure i know what you mean..

Comment: where is Chatpat defined? inside the broadcastreceiver?

Answer (score 1):

In Chatpat you have `chatinput.add(name);` but `chatInput` is declared as
 `ArrayList<String> chatinput = null;` and it is not instantiate anywhere in your activity. you should declare it as `ArrayList<String> chatinput = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I believe that probably i am manipulating in the wrong the incoming messages, and the way they get passed to the adapter. If i put a static array of data, the adapter works. The thing is that if i run Chatpat(), inside the BroadcastReceiver, even if don't use the incoming messages to pass them as values to Chatpat(), I still get the same Error, so i dont know, if it has to do with a problem that can not be resolved, regarding the way I try to update the UI of the Activity

Comment: Try UserComActivity.this instead of this in ChatAdapter adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, chat_data);

Comment: You should have chatList as a class member and have the code chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); inside onCreate.

Comment: I saw you declare chatList as a class member, so that is ok. still findViewById should be in onCreate. Does your layout contain a ListView with id = R.id.listView1?

Comment: i made some of the changes you told me, and now i am getting, 03-26 02:22:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Comment: I was getting there, a NullPoiterException before, that is the line inside the BroadcastReceiver, where i call Chatpat() and pass her the two incoming Strings

Comment: Yes it has a ListView with that name

Comment: Your chat_data[] has no value in it, it is an empty array of chatInput size.

Comment: But is it not supposed here to have the values of chatinput added to it :chatinput.toArray(chat_data)

Comment: The first time the exception occurs, is inside BroadcastReceiver, when the values are passed to Chatpat(), and the second inside Chatpat()

Comment: Now it is the line where you have chatinput.toArray(chat_data);

Comment: I can not understand why this happens though. I am able to print the values of message_name and message_chat inside the BroadcastReceiver, right before it crashes

Comment: Your array dimension is all screw up. Just be patient. You should declare it as Chat[] chat_data in the member declaration. and in the body of Chatpat you do not need to put Chat[] in front just chat_data = ....

Comment: your data structure is a mess, you should change your ChatAdapter to ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Chat> objects) and go from there.